# Faster clock or more cores for best performance of video editing?

Tags: processor, video-editing

I will be configuring a new Windows-based computer in the next few weeks.  This will be a general purpose computer, but will be used on a fairly regular basis for video processing (Sony Vegas) and video rendering.  My current computer indicates that Sony Vegas does use all cores when rendering.  But in looking at CPU options for my upcoming system, is there an online performance comparison tool I can use to figure out which CPU will give me the fastest video render times within my CPU cost budget?  There is quite a variety of cpu models with variances in architecture, clock speed, number of cores, onboard cache, etc.  What I don't know is if in my CPU-intensive video rendering if a higher clock and fewer cores, or slower clock by more cores will give me better performance, assuming sufficient memory, SSD, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Video editing and rendering is mostly multithreaded, so if frequency obviously matters, core & thread count is the most important.

That is why GPU can be a good solution too. If you planned to put a GPU anyway, that could be an option for faster renderering as a GPU has way more cores than a CPU. In this case, I would recommend a "cheap" 6 cores like the Ryzen 2600, depending on your budget of course, with a good GPU.